# Accidentally deleted storyboard from the project, but I have the .storyboardc file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I somehow managed to delete my MainStoryboard.storyboard from my Xcode project, and it's not in the folder either. However, I have the MainStoryboard.storyboardc file in my iPhone simulator folder. I'm assuming this is the compiled version? Is there any way I can get it back into Xcode as a normal storyboard? Thanks much!

Comment: I can't help with the recovery of your storyboard, but it would be a really good idea to use version control. Xcode supports both Git and Subversion and if nothing else, it can help out a lot in situations like this one.

Comment: Is it in your system Trash?

Comment: Or time machine? It's a shame people need to get burned before they realise VCS or backups are a good idea...

Comment: You have learned that losing your files is not fun.
I recommend you look into using Git for your development.
It acts not only as backup, but also keeps track of all your changes to your codebase for all versions, so you can easily make an older version of your software. You can learn more about Git on http://github.com and learn about using it in simple tutorials there. Best of luck with your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use GitHub all the time,but I stupidly forgot to use it for one of the biggest projects I started to do haha. I've been able to recreate most of the storyboard, and I've begun to appreciate IBoutlets in the source files :)